# Line Graph Doubt

Tags: graph-theory

The line graph $L(G)$ of a simple graph $G$ is defined as follows:

There is exactly one vertex $v(e)$ in $L(G)$ for each edge $e$ in $G$.

For any two edges $e$ and $e'$ in $G$, $L(G)$ has an edge between $v(e)$ and $v(e')$, if and only if $e$ and $e'$ are incident with the same vertex in $G$.

Which of the following statements is/are TRUE?

1. The line graph of a cycle is a cycle.
2. The line graph of a clique is a clique.
3. The line graph of a planar graph is planar.
4. The line graph of a tree is a tree.

I have already done the following:

1. The line graph of a cycle is a cycle.
2. [See below.]
3. The line graph of a planar graph is planar. Proof by counter-example: Let $G$ have $5$ vertices and $9$ edges which is a planar graph but $L(G)$ isn't a planar graph because then it will have $25$ edges; therefore, $|E|\leq 3\cdot|V|-6$ is violated.
4. The line graph of a tree is a tree. By counter-example: Try drawing a simple tree which has a root node. The root node has one child $A$ and node $A$ has two children $B$ and $C$. Draw its line graph according to given rules in question and you will get a cycle graph of $3$ vertices.

My doubt is that I can't figure out 2. The line graph of a clique is a clique. Please help me out here.

Comment: In your example for (R) are you sure $L(G)$ has $25$ edges? I only count $24$ (which is enough). Anyway isn't the star graph $K_{1,5}$ a simpler example? The line graph is $K_5$ which is not planar. As for (Q) what is the line graph of $K_4$? Can't you find two edges in $K_4$ which have no common vertex?

Comment: Yes it will have 25 edges using this formula http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301490/find-an-expression-for-the-number-of-edges-of-lg-in-terms-of-the-degrees-of

Comment: The line graph of a clique will be a clique iff every two edges of the clique are adjacent.  Are they?

Comment: @JohnLucas According to that formula the number of edges in $L(G)$ is $$\frac{4\cdot3}2+\frac{4\cdot3}2+\frac{4\cdot3}2+\frac{3\cdot2}2+\frac{3\cdot2}2=6+6+6+3+3=24.$$

Comment: Someone edited the question i already given that Let G have 5 vertices and 9 edges which is a planar graph in which a node has degree 2 and remaining node has degree 4 so it will be 25 then @bof

Comment: @JohnLucas There is no such graph. Did you try to draw it? If there are $5$ vertices, each vertex of degree $4$ must be joined to all the other vertices, including your supposed vertex of degree $2$. No, there is (up to isomorphism) only one (simple) graph with $5$ vertices and $9$ edges; it's the graph you get by removing one edge from the clique $K_5$; its degree sequence is $4,4,4,3.3$ (the endpoints of the missing edge lose one degree); and its **line graph** has $24$ edges.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $G$ be a clique on the $n$ vertices $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n\}$ for $n \ge 4$. Then edges $e_1 = x_1x_2$ and $e_2=x_3x_4$ do not share a vertex. So are $v(e_1)$ and $v(e_2)$ adjacent to each other in $L(G)$?

If you want to look at this another way, $L(K_n)$ has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ vertices. But for each $e \in K_n$, the vertex $v(e)$ has degree only $2(n-2)$ [make sure you see why]. Note that $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} - 1$ $>>$ $2(n-2)$ for $n > 6$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $K_{n}=(V(K_{n}),E(K_{n}))$ be a complete graph of $n$ vertices, then $|E(K_{n})|=\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$, and $|V(L(K_{n}))|=|E(K_{n})|=\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

$L(K_{n})$ is a complete graph (clique) if and only if $|E(L(K_{n}))|=\dfrac{|V(L(K_{n}))|(|V(L(K_{n}))|-1)}{2}$.

To count the number of edges in $L(K_{n})$, it suffices to note that $\forall v \in V(L(K_{n}))$, $deg(v)=2(n-2)$, and to use the fact that $\sum\limits_{v \in V(L(K_{n}))}deg(v)=2|E(L(K_{n}))|$.